# m2e egit connector (for SCM) on Eclipse Photon failure

Tags: eclipse, maven, version-control, egit, eclipse-photon

I'm unable to install above via Marketplace. Detailed error for missing dependency is as follows:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201509090157 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201509090157)
>   Missing requirement: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201509090157 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit 0.14.0.201509090157) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.egit.core [3.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201509090157 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201509090157)
>   To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.sonatype.m2e.egit [0.14.0.201509090157,0.14.0.201509090157]

I noticed this has happened earlier, most often when there is a newer version of Eclipse. Anyway I can't find a certain software site or a valid package to work around it.

Is there anything I can do except go back to Oxygen?

Comment: The m2e egit version 0.X is too old...Really Photon ?

Comment: This looks really old. It says it wants an EGit core version **less than** 5.0.0 - but the current version is 5.0.0 so it doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes this happens in eclipse photon. Where can I download the latest version of Egit as standalone so that it can be installed as archive source in eclipse? Sorry, I didn't get to manage this...

Comment: There is an open bug about this problem: [Bug 544231](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544231). Feel free to upvote or share any additional findings!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I managed to get it installed by going to
Help -> Install New Software -> Work with: 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-egit/0.15.1/N/0.15.1.201806191431/

It seems to have installed without any problems, but I must admit, I haven't actually used it yet.

Comment: To use this URL I also had to update egit from: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/

Comment: Even after this, it did not work for me. Complained about not being able to rename a folder while checking out a repository :-(

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: Installation eventually worked, checking out a project did not (Windows 10 64 Bit Enterprise edition).

Comment: For Eclipse 2019.06 (4.12.0) use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-egit/0.15.1/N/LATEST/ as the one above did not work for me